# how to insert a row back in same table with a column count increase by +1

Tags: sql, db2

how to insert a row back in same table with a column count increase by  +1

```
insert into Columns
select columns
where count of column 3 increase by 1
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you want..

Comment: i need to copy a row from table and insert it back in same table with a column's value (numeric) increased by +1 value

Comment: what kind of where clause is this: "where count of column 3 increase by 1"? What are you counting? Is "Columns" really your table name and column name? You need to update your question with your table design, with before and after pictures of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
insert into YourTable (column1, column2, column3, column4)
select column4, column1, column2, column3 from YourTable
```

In that case data will be copied into `YourTable` and data from first column will be in second column, from second in third ... data from the last column will be in first.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to take a column and increase the value of one column by one, I don't see why you'd take it out and insert it again when you can just [`UPDATE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29) the data:

```
UPDATE sometable
SET somecolumn = somecolumn + 1
WHERE someothercolumn = somevalue
```

Comment: i dont have to update but have to insert an new row wirth increased sequence number

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, maybe you just want an [identity column](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html).

If you create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
)
```

This should make it so every time you insert a row into `myTable`, the new row has an `id` which is one greater than any other in the table.

Presumably, you can `ALTER` a table to add an identity column too.

I used DB2 syntax because that's what this is tagged as. If you're using another database, the syntax will be [much simpler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).